# Release Management : add a link to a DashBoard in Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, ms-release-management

Is it possible to add a link to the latest release in a DashBoard in Visual Studio Team Services (TFS Online)? The goal for us is to provide a way for a StakeHolder to have access to the release not from his dashboard.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pin a release definition to a dashboard by right clicking the definition

[image: Add to dashboard]

And it looks something like this on the dashboard

[image: dashboard]

You can also add a markdown widget if you just want a hyperlink or link to a share
[image: Markdown]

Worth keeping an eye on the marketplace too as new widgets are popping up all the time.

[Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vsts)

Comment: I'm running TFS 2015 update 2.1 - I have no option in the 'right-click' menu to add to dashboard. Bug?

Comment: Probably a permissions issue,  Are you a project Admin or a Team Admin for the team whose dashboard you're trying to edit?

Comment: The link you supplied is for Team Services, not Team Foundation Server. I have full permissions across the entire platform, so that's not an issue. Confirmed this feature doesn't exist on-premise installations: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3070efca-0066-42a0-8898-b5d64ef41b91/no-longer-able-to-pin-releases-to-the-dashboard?forum=tfsbuild